# Check if timestamp is inside range

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, time, timestamp, comparison

I'm trying to obtain the following:

```
+--------------------+
|work_time | day_shift|
+--------------------+
| 00:45:40 |      No  |
| 10:05:47 |      Yes |
| 15:25:28 |      Yes |
| 19:38:52 |      No  |
```

where I classify the "work_time" into "day_shift".
"Yes" - if the time falls between 09:00:00 and 18:00:00
"No" - otherwise

My "work_time" is in datetime format showing only the time. I tried the following, but I'm just getting "No" for everything.

```py
df = df.withColumn('day_shift', when(df.work_time >= to_timestamp(lit('09:00:00'), 'HH:mm:ss') & df.work_time <= to_timestamp(lit('18:00:00'), 'Yes').otherwise('No'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Column` class method [`between`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.between.html#pyspark.sql.Column.between). It works for both, *timestamps* and *strings* in format `"HH:mm:ss"`. Use this:

```py
F.col("work_time").between("09:00:00", "18:00:00")
```

Full test:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('00:45:40',), ('10:05:47',), ('15:25:28',), ('19:38:52',)], ['work_time'])

day_shift = F.col("work_time").between("09:00:00", "18:00:00")
df = df.withColumn("day_shift", F.when(day_shift, "Yes").otherwise("No"))

df.show()
# +---------+---------+
# |work_time|day_shift|
# +---------+---------+
# | 00:45:40|       No|
# | 10:05:47|      Yes|
# | 15:25:28|      Yes|
# | 19:38:52|       No|
# +---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, spark doesn't have so-called "Time" data type, it only supports either `TimestampType` or `DateType`. Therefore, I believe the `work_time` in your dataframe is a string.

Secondly, when you check your `func.to_timestamp(func.lit('09:00:00'), 'HH:mm:ss')` in selection statement, it will show:

```
+--------------------------------+
|to_timestamp(09:00:00, HH:mm:ss)|
+--------------------------------+
|1970-01-01 09:00:00             |
+--------------------------------+
only showing top 1 row
```

The best way to achieve is either split your `work_time` column to `hour`, `minute` and `second` column respectively and do the filtering, or add a date value in your `work_time` column before any timestamp filtering.

Comment: My work_time column originated from another column containing timestamps. I just filtered out the times into the work_time column.